# How do you make a bot transfer it's ownership(of a discord server) to a user using the discord.py API?

Tags: python, discord.py

Yes, the bot is the ownership account.
I'm aware that in the discord.js documentation there are hints but I need it in discord.py

If anyone has an idea that would be great, thank you.

Comment: You can't "transfer" ownership of a bot, since it is just an application, tied to an account. All you could do is share the bot token, secret, etc. which is totally **not** advisable. Why would you want to transfer the ownership of the bot anyways? Just share the source code and have the other person create their own application?

Comment: You misunderstood, in a discord server, the Bot has ownership of the server, as displayed by a crown next to the name.

Comment: Oh okay. But this doesn't quite come clear from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer ownership of a guild via the [`guild.edit()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.edit) function.
To set the new owner use

```py
await guild.edit(owner = member)
```

where `member` is of type `discord.Member` and is supposed to be the new owner.